# How to switch between releases of Java on Mac OSX?

Tags: java

I have 3 releases of Java 8 installed on Mac OSX.  I need to switch temporarily to an older release, because a program I use has a problem with the newer release.

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines >>> ls -al
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  5 root  wheel  160 Nov  1 11:12 .
drwxr-xr-x  4 root  wheel  128 Sep 21 00:02 ..
drwxr-xr-x  3 root  wheel   96 Jun 16  2017 jdk1.8.0_131.jdk
drwxr-xr-x  3 root  wheel   96 Oct 16  2017 jdk1.8.0_144.jdk
drwxr-xr-x  3 root  wheel   96 Oct 24 12:02 jdk1.8.0_181.jdk

/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines >>> which java
/usr/bin/java

/usr/bin >>> ls -al java
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  74 Nov  1 11:03 java -> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/java
```

How do I make jdk1.8.0_144.jdk the current system version of java temporarily until I can get the program updated?

Thanks,

Comment: By setting $PATH environment variable.

export PATH=<latest_jdk>:$PATH

Comment: Yes, one of the answers to that question contained a link that is what I was looking for:  https://gist.github.com/hogmoru/8e02cf826c840914a8ed93fd418ed88e

Basically, I just needed to go into this directory /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents

Then I needed to:
sudo mv Info.plist Info.plist.disabled

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run this command to see Java versions that currently you have :

```
/usr/libexec/java_home -V
```

The output will be like this :

```
Matching Java Virtual Machines (2):
1.8, x86_64:   "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8/jdk/Contents/Home
1.6, x86_64:   "Java SE 6" /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Select your desired `Java` version as **default** by following `export` command :
 `export JAVA_HOME ='/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.6'` in your shell’s init file.

I hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

Setting your `JAVA_HOME` environment variable to your desired JDK version should do the trick.

Add `export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home` to your `.bash_profile`

Comment: As @sainageswar-s mentioned in the comments above, you may also have to pre-pend the `$JAVA_HOME` environment variable to `$PATH`. The problem is by default there's a symbolic link at `/usr/bin/java` that may get picked up.